# How to add permanent ecmp route in linux

Tags: linux, route

I'm creating following ECMP route in linux -

```
[root@compute2 ~]# ip route add 30.1.1.1/32 nexthop via 10.1.1.10 weight 1 nexthop via 20.1.1.10 weight 1
[root@compute2 vagrant]# ip route show 30.1.1.1
30.1.1.1 
        nexthop via 10.1.1.10 dev eth2 weight 1 
        nexthop via 20.1.1.10 dev eth3 weight 1
```

How to make it persistent, so that it gets configured after reboot ?

Comment: What's your GNU/Linux Distro?

Comment: It is CentOS and RHEL